# Как определить путь к фоновому изображению

Tags: php, img, background-image

Никогда не использовал фоновые изображения, тут споткнулся на галерее на них основанной. Не могу понять как указать путь к фоновому изображению. Обычный img отображается а div нет.

```
<div style="background:url('/bw.jpg')"></div>
<img src="/bw.jpg">
```

Comment: Вообще, путь указывается по тому же принципу, что и в обычном `<img>`. Проверьте в консоли, нашлось ли изображение в принципе. Но проблема вероятнее всего в позиционировании, размере и т.п. бэкграунда относительно блока.

Comment: да, Вы правы. указал высоту блока и картинка "нашлась" :-)